# How to generate list of dates taking into consideration the month of startDate and endDate when they fall in different month?

Tags: java, localdate

Assuming i have `startDate`, `endDate`,`currentDate`

`1.` I want to ignore instance where `startDate` and `endDate` fall outside of `currentDate` month.

`2.` When `startDate` and `currentDate` are of the same month but `endDate` has a month greater than `currentDate`, then create a list between `startDate` to end day of `startDate`s month.

`3.` When `endDate` is of the same month as `currentDate` and `startDate` is less than `currentDate` month, then create a list between `endDate` and first day of `currentDate`

I would like some help with a method to handle this.

Thank You

Comment: Can you include your attempt thus far?

Comment: How should the list look like? I don't understand the question.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets make a method that creates a sequence of dates given a start and stop date. This method makes use of `plusDays` in `LocalDate` to generate dates in a while loop.

```
public static List<LocalDate> makeDateInterval(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    List<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (startDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
        return list;
    }
    LocalDate nextDate = startDate;

    while (nextDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
        list.add(nextDate);
        nextDate = nextDate.plusDays(1);
    }
    list.add(endDate);
    return list;
}
```

To sort out what the start and stop date is we need a simple logic to compare the months of the given dates and if we have a valid interval we call the above method

```
public static List<LocalDate> buildDateRange(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, LocalDate currentDate) {
    LocalDate firstDate = null;
    LocalDate secondDate = null;

    if (startDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()) {
        firstDate = startDate;
        secondDate = currentDate;
    }

    if (endDate.getMonth() == currentDate.getMonth()) {
        secondDate = endDate;
        if (firstDate == null) {
            firstDate = currentDate;
        }
    }

    if (firstDate == null || secondDate == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>(); //No valid interval, return empty list
    }

    return makeDateInterval(firstDate, secondDate);
}
```

A simple test today February 1st

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
   LocalDate start = now.minusDays(5);
   LocalDate end = now.plusDays(5);

   System.out.println("Now: " + now + ", start: " + start + ", end: " +end);
   List<LocalDate> list = buildDateRange(start, end, now);

   for (LocalDate d : list) {
       System.out.println(d);
   }
}
```

generates the following output

> Now: 2019-02-01, start: 2019-01-27, end: 2019-02-06
>   2019-02-01
>   2019-02-02
>   2019-02-03
>   2019-02-04
>   2019-02-05
>   2019-02-06